# Backbone sub-routes for tabs within a view

Tags: backbone.js, tabs, backbone-views, backbone-routing

I have a view with two tabs. When clicking on a tab, I want to:

1. show the tab
2. change the hash to `#view/tabName`

If the hash change between `#view/tab1` and `#view/tab2`, the route won't trigger, but the view show **tab2**. If the hash changed from `#anotherView` to `#view/tabName`, the route will trigger, and render the view with initial tab **tabName**.

To summary, when the hash changes between hashes with the same prefix `#view`, the **view** will handle the event, else the **router**.

Here's my current code.

```
// router.js
define('router', [
    'jquery'
    , 'underscore'
    , 'backbone'
    , 'SomeView'

], function (
    $, _, backbone, SomeView
) {
    var router;

    router = backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            'some-view': someView
            , 'some-view/:tab': someView
        }
        , initialize: function () {

        }
        , someView: function (tab) {
            var view; 
            view = new SomeView(tab);
            view.on('router:changeTab', function (tab) {
                that.navigate('some-view/' + tab);
            });


        }
    });
    return router;
});

// someView.js
define('SomeView', [
    'jquery'
    , 'underscore'
    , 'backbone'
], function (
    $, _, backbone
) {
    var SomeView;

    SomeView = backbone.View.extend({

        initialize: function (options) {
            this.tab = options.tab;

        }
        , render: function (callback) {

            // show the initial tab if given
            if (this.tab) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    that.$el.find('[href="#' + that.tab + '-tab"]').click();
                }, 0);
            }

            return this;
        }
        , events: {
            , 'click .nav-tabs>li>a': 'showTab' // enable tabs
        }

        , showTab: function (e) {
            var that, tab, tabs;
            that = this;
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).tab('show');  // I'm using bootstrap tab plugin
            // update hash
            tab = $(e.currentTarget).attr('href').split('-')[0].split('#')[1];
            that.trigger('router:changeTab', tab);
            // What I didn't know is how to prevent the handler from being 
            // invoked when the user press backward/forward button on the browser,
            // and let this view handle it (show the corresponding tab). 
        }
    return SomeView;
});
```

Comment: So how do you switch between tabs any javascript plugins, Yes!! then hook to the event(`TabChange`) and the view responds by changing the hash without invoking the router callback else follow this methodology view changes the url hash, router subscribes to the tab change hash , invokes a event on the collection/model displayed in these tabs so that views can subscribe and act accordingly

Comment: so if you don't want to trigge a route you should use the navigate method with the options specifying not to invoke callback http://backbonejs.org/#Router-navigate

Comment: @Deeptechtons: If I set `replace`, there won't be history of navigating through tabs. But what I want is there still histories, but when user click backward/forward buttons on browser, the handler is depends on the previous page. If the previous page is **some-view**, then keep the user in the same view without reloading it, and just switch the tab. If the previous view is not **some-view**, that the router handle, which will render **some-view** with/without initial tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dynamic routing, where you may specify routes like:

```
routes : {
  "view/:tab_name" : "show_tab",
  "otherRoutes" : "other_methods"
},

show_tab : function(tab_name) {
  // render tab based on the parameter you receive
}
```

so if address bar contains the url #view/tab1 then you'l receive 'tab1' as tab_name parameter in the show_tab method and same for #view/tab2 also.

You can refer [this link](http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-router/) by [Thomas Davis](http://thomasdavis.github.com/) to know more about backbone routers.

Comment: But I don't want the route be triggered when switching between tabs.